# How to change the language of ".$upcoming date." in reminder emails to site users

Tags: php, cron

I urgently need to know how I can make dates appear in Spanish instead of in English in reminder emails sent to users via a cron task. With the current `(".$upcoming_date.")`, the date shown in the emails is like this: `Saturday, 26 November, 2011 21:19`, and I would need this to change into the corresponding Spanish version or into something like `26/11/2011 21:19`.

Answer (score 1):

You will maybe need this function to convert the time if it is store somewhere. Good luck.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
```

Comment: $formatted = date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($upcoming_date));

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You change the value of the `$format` argument you pass to [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).

```
strftime(_($someformat), $sometime)
```

Answer (score 0):

For spanish dates ,You can do:

```
echo strftime("%A %e de %B del %Y - %H:%M:%S", mktime (gmdate("H"), gmdate("i"), gmdate("s")-16200, gmdate("n"), gmdate("j"), gmdate("Y")));
```

Hope it helps